# CURL failed to down load the ENTIRE build log in jenkins

Tags: curl, jenkins

I have a build step in Jenkins:

curl http://localhost:8080/job/%JOB_NAME%/%BUILD_NUMBER%/consoleText > d:\dblog.txt

to download the build log. It does download the file, but it always cuts the file, downloads part of the file only.

more mystery: the actually saved file, d:\dblog.txt, has a random size.

I tried to use --max-time for the curl command, it doesn't seems helping.

I am on windows 7 professional, the workstation has sufficient disk space.

when I create another project with a single step (same as above), the file IS downloaded completely.

How can I resolve this?

thanks,
Heinz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log you can `tail` that file to overcome the problem.

Also, see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14899 . Updating Jenkins to 1618 might resolve this as well.

Source: [Jenkins official changelog](https://jenkins-ci.org/changelog). Ctrl+f + search for string 14899

Comment: Zloj, I have been use the workaround, and it works. Updating Jenkins to 1.608 does not do the trick: still only the first about 5000 lines are saved by CURL/JENKINS.

Comment: @Heinz Jenkins version should be 1618 to include the fix. Edited my answer too. Please come back if you decide to upgrade and tell if this resolved the issue.

Comment: where did you see Jenkins 1618?

Comment: I have updated Jenkins to the latest version 1.630, and CURL downloads the ConsoleText correctly. The issue is resolved. thanks.